# Fixed Position CSS not working on Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I need some assistance with [MorbidStix.com](http://MorbidStix.com) mobile site. I am trying to float the price on the right as it changes with options and have implemented the CSS Fixed position which works when testing on Firefox but not on safari ios.

The mobile site is separate from the desktop site and is triggered by agent.

CSS used:

```
.Fixed {
position: absolute !important;
top: 45px !important;
right: 0;
Background: #fff;
border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px !important;
padding: 12px !important;
box-shadow: 4px 2px 4px #000;
z-index: 999999 !important;
}
```

I was able to boil down the tab to this:

```
 <!-- //Price Tab -->
<div class="Fixed" style="%%GLOBAL_HidePrice%%">
        <div class="Label">%%GLOBAL_PriceLabel%%:</div>
        <div class="Value">
            <em class="ProductPrice VariationProductPrice">%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%</em>
            %%GLOBAL_IncludingExcludingTax%% %%GLOBAL_YouSave%%
        </div>
</div>
<!-- //Price Tab End -->
```

I have inserted this in to the header and it indeed will float on mobile but the price will not populate.

I am lost and could use some direction.

Comment: can you add the css for the fixed element

Comment: The website itself is NOT responsive at all. Are you referring to a m.* version of the website, because there isn't one either.

Comment: I added the CSS I am using and added that the site is indeed mobile but triggered via agent. While testing on firefox, it works perfect. testing on ios it does not.